# iPhone Upload Image to Servlet

Tags: iphone, servlets, webservice-client

I am trying to upload a thumbnail image to a servlet. The servlet code is already present and working with website.

Sample URL http://abcd.com/upload?param1=abc&param2=pqr

The data gets posted on the website but the image does not.

I have tried uploading my image using following code snippets:

**Code 1:**

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageSelect.image, 1.0);
    //NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageSelect.image);

    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data;boundary=%@",boundary];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];        
    [request addValue:@"Keep-Alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString *strFilename = [self getFilePath];
    NSLog(@"filename:[%@]",strFilename);

    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileing\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", strFilename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];


    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:postbody];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //Return string always returned empty
    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

**Code 2**

```
    //NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageSelect.image, 0.7);
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageSelect.image);

    NSString *filename = [self getFilePath];
    //Filename:\\var\\mobile\\Applications\\F2Dxxxx-8656-4208-B398-8D504320FC7B\\Documents\\Image_Photo.jpg        

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL ]];        

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

    NSString *contentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",filename];

    [request addRequestHeader:@"Connection" value:@"Keep-Alive"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:contentType];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[contentString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setTimeOutSeconds:60]; // 1 minute
    [request appendPostData:body];
    [request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

Do let me know where I'm going wrong.

Also I found article on http://insanelycrazy.net/development/faces/viewarticle.xhtml?id=6
But since server code is ready cannot use this snippet.

Following is code is used in Android

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
URL url = new URL(urlString);
Log.i("", "URL : " + url.toString());
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize);
dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
Log.i("", "Before filepath : " + filepath);
filepath = filepath.replace("/", "\\" + "\\");
Log.i("", "After filepath : " + filepath);

dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileing\";filename=\"" + filepath + "\"" + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
while (bytesRead > 0) {
      dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
      bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
      bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
      bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
      progressStatus += bytesRead;
      publishProgress(progressStatus);
}
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
fileInputStream.close();
dos.flush();
dos.close();
```

Regards,
Sumit

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:YOUR URL STRING];
    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //adding header information:
    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [postRequest setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
    [postRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSData *imageData =UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.convertImage);


    NSMutableData *postBody = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userid\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSDictionary *dic = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:PROFILE_DETAILS];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dic valueForKey:@"id"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profilepic\"; filename=\"ipodfile.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
    [postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];


    theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {
        // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
        // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    [postRequest release];
```

Comment: Hi Irshad, As I am unsure of what value is to be store in NSUserDefaults for "PROFILE_DETAILS" key I tried your code by commenting those two lines. Only textual data was sent to the server. Also I get blank response, tried to log responseData by using NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);  Kindly guide me through. Thank you.

Comment: Hi All,

There were some server issues so the images were not getting posted.

I am able to upload the file on my server now.

I am using ASIHTTPRequest to upload. 
Getting empty response if upload is successful. Any clues why?

Now trying to upload video using same code.

Thank you. For your time and response.

Regards,
Sumit